# Implementing a task deletion function in Assembly x86 tasm

Tags: assembly, file-io, x86, file-handling, tasm

I'm currently working on an Assembly x86 tasm language program for task management that allows adding and viewing tasks. However, I've been struggling to implement a function to delete a specific task.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
sir db 80 dup('$') 
m2 db 'Introduceti sirul:$'
m4 db '1. Add task', 13, 10, '$'
m5 db '2. View tasks', 13, 10, '$'
filename db 'tasks.txt',0
handle dw ?
strLength dw ?
t_handle dw ?
newline db 13, 10, '$' ; New line characters
menuChoice db ?
buffer db 2000 dup(0)
.code
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    
    mov ah, 9h
    mov dx, offset m4
    int 21h
    
    mov ah, 9h
    mov dx, offset m5
    int 21h
    
    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    mov menuChoice, al
    
    cmp menuChoice, '1'
    je add_task
    cmp menuChoice, '2'
    je view_tasks
    cmp menuChoice, '3'
    je delete_aux
    
    jmp end_program

view_tasks:
    ; Opening file for reading
    mov ah, 3Dh 
    mov al, 0 
    mov dx, offset filename 
    int 21h 
    mov handle, ax 

    ; Reading file contents
    mov ah, 3Fh 
    mov bx, handle 
    mov dx, offset sir 
    mov cx, 80 
    int 21h 

    ; Displaying tasks line by line with incrementing numbers
    mov si, offset sir

    display_loop:
        ; Check if end of file or end of buffer
        cmp byte ptr [si], '$'
        je end_display
        ; Print character to screen
        mov ah, 02h 
        mov dl, [si] 
        int 21h 
        ; Move to the next character
        inc si
        jmp display_loop

    end_display:
    ; Close the file
    mov ah, 3Eh ; File close service
    mov bx, handle ; File handle
    int 21h ; File close interrupt

    jmp end_program

delete_aux:
    cmp menuChoice, '3' ; Check if the choice is for delete
    jne view_tasks ; If not, jump to view_tasks
    jmp delete_task ; If yes, jump to delete_task

add_task:
    ; Clearing the buffer
    mov ah, 0Ah
    mov dx, offset sir
    int 21h

    ; Adding a task to the file
    ; Prompting for task input
    mov ah, 9h
    mov dx, offset m2
    int 21h
    
    mov bx,0 
    mov cx,80 
    mov ah,3fh
    mov dx,offset sir
    int 21h

    mov ah, 9h
    mov dx, offset sir
    int 21h

    ; Calculating string length
    mov si, offset sir
    add si, 2
    mov cx, 0 ; Initialize count
    count_length:
        cmp byte ptr [si], '$' 
        je end_count
        inc cx 
        inc si
        jmp count_length 
    
    end_count:
    mov strLength, cx 

    ; Opening file for appending at the end
    mov ah, 3Dh 
    mov al, 2 ;
    mov dx, offset filename
    int 21h 
    mov handle, ax 

    ; Positioning at the end of the file
    mov ah, 42h 
    mov al, 2 
    mov bx, handle 
    mov cx, 0 
    mov dx, 0 
    int 21h 

    ; Writing string to file
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, handle 
    mov dx, offset sir 
    mov cx, strLength
    int 21h

; Writing newline to file
    mov ah, 40h 
    mov bx, handle
    mov dx, offset newline 
    mov cx, 2
    int 21h

    ; Closing the file
    mov ah, 3Eh 
    mov bx, handle
    int 21h
   
    jmp view_tasks

delete_task:
    
    jmp view_tasks ; Redirect to view tasks after deletion


end_program:
    mov ah,4Ch
    int 21h
end
```

I've tried implementing a 'Delete task' option and managed file operations using termination characters 13, 10, '$', but I can't get the hang of it.

```
delete_task:
    ; Prompt for task number to delete
    mov ah, 9h
    mov dx, offset m_delete_prompt
    int 21h

    ; Read user input for the task number to delete
    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    sub al, '0' 
    mov bl, al

    ; Opening the file for reading and writing
    mov ah, 3Dh 
    mov al, 2 
    mov dx, offset filename 
    int 21h
    mov handle, ax 

    ; Reading and deleting the desired task
    mov ah, 3Fh 
    mov bx, handle 
    mov dx, offset buffer 
    mov cx, 2000 
    int 21h

    mov si, offset buffer
    mov di, si

    delete_loop:
        cmp byte ptr [si], '$' 
        je end_delete
        mov al, [si]
        cmp al, 13 
        je check_next_char
        mov [di], al 
        inc di
        inc si
        jmp delete_loop

    check_next_char:
        inc si ; Move to next character (LF)
        mov al, [si]
        cmp al, 10
        je delete_task_found
        mov byte ptr [di], 13 
        inc di
        mov [di], al
        inc di 
        inc si
        jmp delete_loop

    delete_task_found:
        ; Check if it's the desired task to delete
        sub al, '0' 
        cmp al, bl  
        je skip_task   
        jmp copy_task

    skip_task:
        ; Skip the task to delete
        mov al, [si]
        cmp al, 13  
        jne skip_task 
        jmp delete_loop

    copy_task:
        ; Copy the task to keep it
        mov [di], al
        inc di 
        inc si 
        jmp delete_loop

    end_delete:
        ; Truncate the file at the updated position
        mov ah, 40h
        mov bx, handle
        mov dx, offset buffer
        sub di, offset buffer
        int 21h

        ; Close the file
        mov ah, 3Eh 
        mov bx, handle
        int 21h

    jmp view_tasks

; Data Section
m_delete_prompt db 'Enter the task number to delete: $'
```

For the following tasks:

```
task1
task2
task3
task4
task5
```

This is what I got:

```
task1
task2
task3
task4
task5
task1Útask2Útask3Útask4Útask5Ú                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ÿÿùtâ
```

Comment: Why would you do this is assembly?

Comment: It's for a school project. We're diving computer architecture and low-level programming.  Plus, it's a challenge I'm taking on

Comment: Number of task for deletion is stored in `bl`. Few lines below `bx` is filled with file handle and later in `delete_task_found:` code compares `al` with `bl`, which is not number of the task anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As I said in comment above, the number of task for deletion should be saved. So `push bx` does the job. Restore this value by using `pop bx` before `delete_loop:`.
2. This instruction `cmp byte ptr [si], '$'` at the begining of `delete_loop` searches for `$` but `buffer` is filled with `0`'s. So this loop could run forever
   unless somewhere in memory there is `$`. So either fill buffer with `$` or add variable `eotb db '$'` after `buffer` to mark end of the buffer.
3. What is going on inside `delete_loop` is this..

   - if byte is `0d` go to `check_next_char:`
   - if byte is `0a` go to `delete_task_found:`
   - `al = 0a`, so this instruction `sub al '0'` doesn't substract `'0'` from `'1' - '9'` to get proper task number
   - other characters `t`,`a`,`s`,`k`,`1 - 9` are skipped
4. I can propose this solution...

   - Each record in file looks like this `task 1-9 0d 0a`
   - First number of the task is at location `buffer + 4`
   - Next are every 7 bytes:

     `buffer + 4 + 7`

     `buffer + 4 + 7 + 7`

     `buffer + 4 + 7 + 7 + 7`

     `buffer + 4 + 7 + 7 + 7 ...`
   - If program finds number of the task in file it modifies buffer and writes new data to file
     else `$` means there is no task in file.
5. I wrote code just for deleting tasks

   ```
   .model small
   .stack 100h
   .data
   sir db 80 dup('$') 
   m2 db 'Introduceti sirul:$'
   m4 db '1. Add task', 13, 10, '$'
   m5 db '2. View tasks', 13, 10, '$'
   m6 db '3. Del tasks', 13, 10, '$'   

   filename db 'code60t.txt',0
   filesize dw ?
   handle dw ?
   strLength dw ?
   t_handle dw ?
   newline db 13, 10, '$' ; New line characters
   menuChoice db ?
   buffer db 70 dup('$')

   m_delete_prompt db 13,10,'Enter the task number to delete: $'
   task_doesnt_exists db 13,10,'This task is not in the file.',13,10,'$'
   del_task db 13,10,'Deleting task number $'  

   .code
   start:
   mov ax,@data
   mov ds,ax

   mov ah, 9h
   mov dx, offset m4
   int 21h

   mov ah, 9h
   mov dx, offset m5
   int 21h

   mov ah, 9h
   mov dx, offset m6
   int 21h

   mov ah, 1h
   int 21h
   mov menuChoice, al

   mov ah, 9h
   mov dx, offset newline
   int 21h

   cmp menuChoice, '1'
   je add_task
   cmp menuChoice, '2'
   je view_tasks
   cmp menuChoice, '3'
   je delete_aux

   jmp end_program

   view_tasks:
   ; Opening file for reading
   mov ah, 3Dh 
   mov al, 2 
   mov dx, offset filename 
   int 21h 
   mov handle, ax 

   ; Reading file contents
   mov ah, 3Fh 
   mov bx, handle 
   mov dx, offset sir 
   mov cx, 80 
   int 21h 

   ; Displaying tasks line by line with incrementing numbers
   mov si, offset sir

   display_loop:
       ; Check if end of file or end of buffer
       cmp byte ptr [si], '$'
       je end_display
       ; Print character to screen
       mov ah, 02h 
       mov dl, [si] 
       int 21h 
       ; Move to the next character
       inc si
       jmp display_loop

   end_display:
   ; Close the file
   mov ah, 3Eh ; File close service
   mov bx, handle ; File handle
   int 21h ; File close interrupt

   jmp end_program

   delete_aux:
   cmp menuChoice, '3' ; Check if the choice is for delete
   jne view_tasks ; If not, jump to view_tasks
   jmp delete_task ; If yes, jump to delete_task

   add_task:
   ; Clearing the buffer
   mov ah, 0Ah
   mov dx, offset sir
   int 21h

   ; Adding a task to the file
   ; Prompting for task input
   mov ah, 9h
   mov dx, offset m2
   int 21h

   mov bx,0 
   mov cx,80 
   mov ah,3fh
   mov dx,offset sir
   int 21h

   mov ah, 9h
   mov dx, offset sir
   int 21h

   ; Calculating string length
   mov si, offset sir
   add si, 2
   mov cx, 0 ; Initialize count
   count_length:
       cmp byte ptr [si], '$' 
       je end_count
       inc cx 
       inc si
       jmp count_length 

   end_count:
   mov strLength, cx 

   ; Opening file for appending at the end
   mov ah, 3Dh 
   mov al, 2 ;
   mov dx, offset filename
   int 21h 
   mov handle, ax 

   ; Positioning at the end of the file
   mov ah, 42h 
   mov al, 2 
   mov bx, handle 
   mov cx, 0 
   mov dx, 0 
   int 21h 

   ; Writing string to file
   mov ah, 40h
   mov bx, handle 
   mov dx, offset sir 
   mov cx, strLength
   int 21h

   ; Writing newline to file
   mov ah, 40h 
   mov bx, handle
   mov dx, offset newline 
   mov cx, 2
   int 21h

   ; Closing the file
   mov ah, 3Eh 
   mov bx, handle
   int 21h

   jmp view_tasks

   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    delete_task: 
   ; Prompt for task number to delete
   mov ah, 9h
   mov dx, offset m_delete_prompt
   int 21h

   ; Read user input for the task number to delete
   mov ah, 1h
   int 21h    
   mov bl, al

   push bx             ; save the number of the task

   ;---- file operations

   ; Opening the file for reading and writing
   mov ah, 3Dh 
   mov al, 2 
   mov dx, offset filename 
   int 21h
   mov handle, ax 

   ; Reading from file to buffer
   mov ah, 3Fh 
   mov bx, handle 
   mov dx, offset buffer 
   mov cx, 70 
   int 21h

   ; calculate file size, this value is used later
   mov ah,42h
   mov al,2
   xor cx,cx
   xor dx,dx
   int 21h
   mov filesize, ax

   ; close file, later program uses 3ch because we want to delete old data in file and write modified data
   mov ah, 3eh     
   int 21h

   ;---- buffer operations

   mov si, offset buffer
   add si, 4       ; first location of the task number

   pop bx          ; restore the number of task 

   delete_loop:
       cmp byte ptr [si],'$'       ; check if we reached end of buffer
       je no_tasks
       mov al, [si]                ; task number
       cmp al, bl                  ; is this our task?
       je task_found               ; yes
       add si, 7                   ; no, go to next record
       jmp delete_loop             ; try again

   task_found:                 
       mov ah, 9h                  ; show some messages
       mov dx, offset del_task
       int 21h

       mov ah, 2h
       mov dl, bl      
       int 21h     

       mov ah, 9h
       mov dx, offset newline
       int 21h

       add si, 3                   ; start of the next record  
       mov di, si
       sub di, 7                   ; start of the record we want to delete
                                   ; do this by moving rest of the tasks up 7 bytes

       mov al, 10                  ; we can have max 9 tasks (9 * 7 bytes = 63) + 7 bytes of '$' to clear end of the list
       mov ah, 0

       sub bl, 30h
       sub al, bl                   ; calculate how many bytes to copy
       mov bl, 7
       mul bl      
       mov cx, ax          

       tasks_move:
           mov al, [si]
           mov [di], al
           inc si
           inc di
           dec cx
           jnz tasks_move

       write_to_file:
           mov ah, 3ch         
           mov dx, offset filename
           mov cx, 2           
           int 21h             

           ; Writing modified buffer to file
           mov bx, ax
           mov ah, 40h         
           mov dx, offset buffer 
           mov cx, filesize
           sub cx,7
           int 21h     

           mov ah, 3eh     
           int 21h

   jmp view_tasks

   no_tasks:
       mov ah, 9h
       mov dx, offset task_doesnt_exists
       int 21h     

   jmp view_tasks


   end_program:
       mov ah,4Ch
       int 21h
   end start
   ```

Comment: This was really useful, easy to follow and understand. This works like a charm. Thank you very much!